# How to convert LD ladder to ST literal language?

Tags: codesys

I'm using CoDeSys software to develop. Now, I have just completed code in LD (ladder). I would like to change (convert) LD to ST (structured text).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There unfortunately is no way to transform Ladder into Structured Text Language. There are various transformations you can do in codesys in between the different language types, but LD -> ST is not one of them. It is definately not possible in CoDeSys 2.3 referrin to my past experiences in that version, and as far as I've seen it's not in the newer 3.x version as well, hope it'll be added though.